# any API for to implement web-sockets in java

Tags: java, websocket

I have a requirement to do a web based interactive application in which server could push data in to the clients(web browser , android phone or JME phone). I have suggested to use Websockets rather than reverse ajax. Is there any nice framework for java to implement websockets. Please suggest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following very similar sounding Java servers / frameworks have web socket support:

- [Jetty](http://jetty.codehaus.org/jetty/)
- [Netty](http://www.jboss.org/netty/documentation.html)

Note that web sockets aren't universally supported as a result of [security issues](http://hacks.mozilla.org/2010/12/websockets-disabled-in-firefox-4/) (and because Microsoft doesn't want to).

You could also consider looking at some of the JMS providers that provide JMS to web sockets e.g. HornetQ and ActiveMQ using Stomp.

Answer (score 0):

No need, Java has it's own very intuitive socket library.

api: http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html

tutorial: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/

Comment: My question was about Websockets

Answer (score 0):

[Grizzly](http://grizzly.java.net) also has websockets support for what it's worth.  But one reason to use websockets rather than java.net.Socket is that websockets can traverse firewalls and proxies transparently without having to reconfigure network ports/policies.